# OR condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I am using Magento 2.1.5, and I created 4 customer attribute. I need to set the condition like if any one of the fields is filled, customer session will start.

for one field I am getting the result, but I don't understand how to put this condition for 4 fields.

```
$customerCollection=$this->customerObj->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addAttributeToFilter("customer_attr1" ,$this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());

foreach ($customerCollection as $value) {
        array_push($arry,$value->getData("entity_id"));
    }
```

In this **"customer_attr1"** is one attribute. like same 4 other field is there **"customer_attr2" "customer_attr3" "customer_attr4".**

How to set a condition like if any one field is true, return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$customerCollection=$this->customerObj->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addFieldToFilter(
    array("customer_attr1","customer_attr2","customer_attr3","customer_attr4"),
      array(
          array('eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())
      )
    );
```

Or

```
$customerCollection=$this->customerObj->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addAttributeToFilter(   
    array(
          array('attribute' => 'customer_attr1', 'eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('attribute' => 'customer_attr2', 'eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('attribute' => 'customer_attr3', 'eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()),
          array('attribute' => 'customer_attr4', 'eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())
    )
);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer. after this i have to write "foreach ($customerCollection as $value) {
   array_push($arry,$value->getData("entity_id"));
  }" to return the value. is it will work?    check my updated code.

Comment: try and check then let s see what will be the output. i believe it should still work

Comment: its not working. returning nothing

Comment: try this `foreach ($customerCollection as $value) {
        array_push($arry,$value->getData("entity_id")); print_r($array);
    }`

Comment: and check what you got

Comment: after applying this, if i filled all the field, then only return value, but i want, atleast one field should filled, than also return

Comment: @sam did you check the second solution?

Comment: yes, actually second conditions works only. i got this returns after applying second conditions only.